# How to Keccak 256 hash in front end JavaScript before passing it to my smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, keccak

I would like to build a simple JavaScript (JS) front end that checks if a field submitted is the pre-image of a keccak256 hash I already know in my smart contract. I currently use the following:

Front end JS:

```
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/js-sha3/build/sha3.min.js"></script>
    <script>keccak_ = keccak_256;</script>
    <script lang="javascript">
    .
    .
    $("a#call_preimage").click(function(){
                    var preimage = $("input#preimage").val();
                    var hash_ = keccack_(newNumber);
                    var hash__ = '0x'+ hash_;
                    var params = {from:web3.eth.accounts[0]}
                    contractInstance.checkPreimage(hash__, params, function(error, result){...
```

Solidity:

```
function checkPreimage(uint256 incoming) public {
 if (uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(known_preimage))) == incoming){
 do_something(); }}
 // known_preimage is of type uint 256 as well
```

I can't seem to pass the if condition. I'm certain all other parts of the code work.

Comment: What is `known_preimage` (type and value)?

Comment: I'm also looking for this. I need the first 4 byte of that hash to validate the contract and not sure how to proceed in the front end. Using NodeJS and ethers

Answer (score 4):

You should use web3's `soliditySha3` [utility function](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3).

In your case, since there is only one parameter to be hashed:

```js
// 234 is your preimage
const hash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(new BN('234'));
```

If you wish to hash more than one parameters:

- In solidity

```
uint256 hash = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(known_preimage1, known_preimage_2)));
```

- In javascript

```js
const hash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(
    {t: 'uint256', v: new BN('234')},
    {t: 'address', v: '0x407D73d8a49eeb85D32Cf465507dd71d507100c1'},
);
```

Comment: For anyone who need an online version I made it here https://eth-tools.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/keccak.html