# Passing a hash value to function

Tags: solidity, hash, string, bytes, keccak

I'm trying to authenticate users by comparing the hashes created by backend server and contract. Seems like "byte32" values cannot be coerced into strings. So, instead I'm converting it into uint256. But the function doesn't accept it.

On my backend (I'm using Remix IDE to manually test the smart contract)

```
let hash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(secret+nonce);
console.log(hash);
```

In my smart contract:

```
 function addUser(string calldata _name, uint256 _hash) external{
        require(_hash == uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(secretkey, nonce))));
        lastfmAuth[_name] = msg.sender;
        nonce++;
 }
```

What is the right way to do this?

Somewhat similar question:
[How to Keccak 256 hash in front end JavaScript before passing it to my smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82595/how-to-keccak-256-hash-in-front-end-javascript-before-passing-it-to-my-smart-con)

Comment: Works fine for me. Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: P.S.: I used `sha3` instead of `soliditySha3`.

Comment: sha3 and soliditySha3 gives the same result for me.

Comment: The problem is that when i hash the same string in smart contract, I get a different hash. `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(secretkey, nonce))`

Comment: Can i somehow get the effect of abi.encodePacked with any on JS functions?

Comment: To put it simple, `sha3("xxx")` and `keccak256(abi.encodePacked("xxx"))` give me the same result.

Comment: Just to make sure that you understand: there are no secrets in smart contracts, all data is visible for everyone. So your scheme probably won't work if it relies on something like `secretkey`

Comment: A private variable won't be visible to anyone, right?